# How to catch I/O exception

Tags: .net, io, serial-port

i have been working on this problem for many days but i am stuck in it and cant figure it out. Problem is when i close the port i get this famous error

```
The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request
```

My code is like this

```
 private void MenuItem_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


            try
            {
                port.ReadExisting();
                port.DiscardInBuffer();         
                if (port.IsOpen)
                {

                    port.Close();
                }

                Window1 caster = new Window1(this);
                caster.ShowDialog();
            }
            catch (IOException)
            {

            }
```

When `port.close()` is executed then i get the above stated error. If I unsubscribe to the data received event, even then this error occurs and is not caught by catch statement.
I have searched it and found many examples, all the solutions provided there have tried but it is annoying me every time i work with app.
can anybody help me out of this problem?

Comment: Are you sure it is IOException that is being raised? Maybe try to catch Exception and if is does hit that catch use the debugger to find the type.

Comment: i have tried Exception instead of IOException many times before but same result. Then i thought that it could be IOException thats why i have asked this question.

Comment: Interesting. The Exception should include all exceptions so that implies you're not getting an exception at all. Looking at the message, I'm wondering if the error is outside this code (after). Something along the lines of the I/O operation is still active after thread finishes (either something left "open" or operation is asynchronous). Then when your thread finishes well past your try statement, the system notices an I/O operation pending for a thread that's no longer there, cancels the operation, and give you the execution. But your Try is long gone and unable to catch it.

Comment: Where do you get that error if not in the catch?  Try a global exception handler.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx  And maybe turn on debug of unmanaged code

Comment: I am getting this error right where i close the port. I have also tried the global exception even that is not working. alas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is an uncatchable exception.  It is raised in a worker thread that the SerialPort class starts so that it can fire the DataReceived, ErrorReceived and PinChanged events.  Unhandled exceptions in worker threads terminate the program since .NET 2.0.  Dealing with this behavior is covered in Tip #4 in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2006/10/10/top-5-serialport-tips-_5b00_kim-hamilton_5d00_.aspx).  I won't repeat it here since this is something you should never do, only pure desperation is a good enough reason to contemplate it.

The underlying reason is an unexpected Windows error code, returned by the device driver when you call the Close() method.  A driver should just comply with the request and not bitch about it.  But that gets to be hard to come by with the kind of drivers that emulate a serial port for a USB or BlueTooth device.  Their quality is rather low in general.

You are especially likely to induce such an unexpected error code when you do unwise things with the device.  A very common trap with USB devices in general, they don't give you any way to do something reasonable when your program is misbehaving.  So you scratch your head, shrug and pull the connector.  Now you got two problems.  Some device drivers deal with this very poorly, they just make the device disappear.  Even though the SerialPort class has a handle opened on it.  This does not come to a good end, to put it mildly, that will definitely bomb when you call Close().

Closing the port like you do in your code is also highly unadvisable, something the MSDN article for SerialPort.Close() warns about.  It takes a while for that worker thread to exit, you cannot open the port again until that happened.  It takes an unpredictable number of seconds for that to occur.  The wisdom here is to only ever open the port when you start your program and only ever (or never) close it when you exit.  With never a valid option, albeit that you might notice that the finalizer thread bombs at program exit if the core reason isn't resolved.

So the common advice here is to look for a driver update, *never* mess with the device while you are using it, taking the device out to the parking lot and running it over with your car a couple of times.  And that tip #4.